# how to convert datetime in C#, please Convert this format 27/01/2016 08:00:17 to T,270116,040017

Tags: c#

How to convert `DateTime` in C#? Please `Convert` this format `27/01/2016 08:00:17` to `T,270116,040017`, expected output - `T,270116,040017` , datetime - `27/01/2016 08:00:17`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `DateTime.ParseExact` as well as `AddHours`, then create your custom formatting:

```
string dtStr = "27/01/2016 08:00:17";
DateTime dt = DateTime.ParseExact(dtStr, "d/M/yyyy HH:mm:ss", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
dt = dt.AddHours(-4);
string dtResult = dt.ToString("T,ddMMyy,HHmmss");
```

Result:

```
T,270116,040017
```

Note: Your `DateTime` string format looks rather unusual. Check [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4(v=vs.110).aspx) for more info.

Comment: Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 3):

I cant add comments to Ians post yet but if you use `TryParseExact` then you won't throw exceptions if there are errors.

Example:

```
        string dtStr = "27/01/2016 08:00:17";

        DateTime dt;
        if (DateTime.TryParseExact(dtStr, "d/M/yyyy HH:mm:ss", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.AdjustToUniversal, out dt))
        {
            dt = dt.AddHours(-4);
            MessageBox.Show(dt.ToString("T,ddMMyy,HHmmss"));
        }
```

[DateTimeStyle Options can be read here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/91hfhz89(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: I think your answer is safer due to the `TryParseExact` ;) voted up (+10). Hope the OP choose you as the answer.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the following to get the time now in the format you requested

```
DateTime.Now.ToString("T,ddMMyy,HHmmss");
```

I was assuming the 4 hours difference between formats was a mistake otherwise use the following code to get a -4 hours difference

```
DateTime dt = DateTime.Now;
dt=dt.AddHours(-4);
dt.ToString("T,ddMMyy,HHmmss");
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try it with `.ToString([format])`:

```
string dateTime = new DateTime(2016, 01, 27, 08, 00, 17).AddHours(-4).ToString("T,ddMMyy,HHmmss,");
```

Result: `T,2701216,040017,`

Comment: Thank you very much. Thank you Thank you!